# how to show mysql search results with conditions

Tags: php, mysql

this is my code

```
<?php
$getnews = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT t.idBerita, t.judul, t.headline, t.waktuAsal, t.lokasi, t.isiBerita, t.penulis, t.editor, t.sumber, t.waktuPengambilan, k.idKategori, g.namaKategori FROM tabelberita t, tabelketerangan k, tabelkategori g WHERE g.idKategori=k.idKategori ORDER BY waktuPengambilan DESC");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($getnews)){
    $id = $row['idBerita'];
    $judul = $row['judul'];
    $headline = $row['headline'];
    $waktuAsal = $row['waktuAsal'];
    $lokasi = $row['lokasi'];
    $isiBerita = $row['isiBerita'];
    $penulis = $row['penulis'];
    $editor = $row['editor'];
    $sumber = $row['sumber'];
    $waktuPengambilan = $row['waktuPengambilan'];
    $kategori = $row['kategori'];

    echo '<h3 style="text-align:center; font-size:20px">' .$judul. '<br></h3>';
    echo '<p style="text-align:center"><i>' .$headline. ' - <b>' .$sumber. '</b></i></p><br>';
    echo '<p style="font-size:11px">Oleh: ' .$penulis. '<br>';
    echo 'Editor : ' .$editor. '<br>';
    echo 'Kategori : ' .$kategori. '<br>';
    echo 'Waktu Pengambilan : ' .$waktuPengambilan. '</p><br>';
    echo '<div id="isi' .$id. '" style="display:none;">';
    echo '<p style="text-align:justify">&emsp;' .$isiBerita. '</p></div><br>';
    echo '<a href="javascript:showMore('.$id.')" id="more' .$id. '" style="display:block;"> Read More >></a>';
    echo '<a href="javascript:showLess('.$id.')" id="less' .$id. '" style="display:none;"> Read Less >></a>';
    echo '<br><br><br><br>';
    echo '';            
}
?>
```

i want to show the results of the news with its category. the news and its category are in different table. but it's possible if some news don't have any category tagged to itself.

the problem is, with the above code, i could only show the news that have category tagged to itself, while news that don;t have any category tagged won't be shown. i want all of the news shown, with the news that don't have any category simply just show but with the empty category section.

how to query that?? thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use left outer join so that all the values from news irrespective of it having a category or not.